# accessing the value of an async storage call (get) when it returns a promise

Tags: react-native, asynchronous

I am trying to access the value of payments by calling getData(), but from some reason it is still returning a promise. I have no idea why, I have read a lot of documentation and according to the code I have, it should return a response and not a promise

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Button, TextInput, Modal, Alert, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import EditScreenInfo from '../components/EditScreenInfo';
import { Text, View } from '../components/Themed';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import { useState } from 'react';

const payments: any[] = []

export default function PaymentsScreen(){
    
    const getData = async () => {

        try {
            
            const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
            const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys).then((response) => {

                return response
                
            });

        } catch(e) {
        
            console.log(e)
        }

    }
    
    React.useEffect(() => {

        getData()

    })
    
    const payments = getData()
    console.log(payments[1])

    //error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '1' can't be used to index type 'Promise<void>'.

    
    return (

        <Text> testing </Text>

    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can mix await and a .then.

Something like this should work

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
        const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys();
        const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys);
        return result;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
```

You also want fix your useEffect to only run on mount.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In this bit here:

```
const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys).then((response) => {

   return response
                
});
```

you're returning from the `then` callback, not from your outer `getData` function.
The promise returned from `getData` by using the `async` keyword currently does not contain anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys).then((response) => {

   // logic
                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this, I think you forgot return result. It work for me.

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
      const result = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys).then((response) => {
        return response
      })
      return result
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

    useEffect(async () => {
       const asyncData = await getData()
       debugLog('asyncData', asyncData)
    }, [])
```